# Trying to Extract Weblinks BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, pdf, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to extract all the PDF links on this [page](https://usda.library.cornell.edu/concern/publications/3t945q76s?locale=en#release-items).

My code is :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint

base_url = 'https://usda.library.cornell.edu'

url = 'https://usda.library.cornell.edu/concern/publications/3t945q76s?locale=en#release-items'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).pdf, 'html.parser')
b = []

page = 1
while True:
    pdf_urls = [a["href"] for a in soup.select('#release-items a[href$=".pdf"]')]
    pprint(pdf_urls)
    b.append(pdf_urls)

    m = soup.select_one('a[rel="next"][href]')
    if m and m['href'] != '#':
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(base_url + m['href']).pdf, 'html.parser')
    else:
        break
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'pdf'
```

A similar code for text files work. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'pdf'
```

The method `resquests.get()` always will return a response object:

```
print(requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com/"))
```

will show:

```
<Response [200]>
```

If you check the possible attributes with `dir()` function, you will see that this response object has not a `pdf` attribute:

```
['__attrs__', '__bool__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__enter__', '__eq__', '__exit__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getstate__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__nonzero__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_content', '_content_consumed', '_next', 'apparent_encoding', 'close', 'connection', 'content', 'cookies', 'elapsed', 'encoding', 'headers', 'history', 'is_permanent_redirect', 'is_redirect', 'iter_content', 'iter_lines', 'json', 'links', 'next', 'ok', 'raise_for_status', 'raw', 'reason', 'request', 'status_code', 'text', 'url']
```

You need to use `requests.get(url).content` to make the soup:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content,'html.parser')
```

> I am trying to extract all the PDF links on this page.

Checking the HTML body, you will see that all the files has a `"file_set"` class. You can get the `"href"` directly of this classes with generator expresion

```
pdf_urls = [x.a["href"] for x in soup.find_all(class_ = "file_set")]
```

Printing you will get all the pdf links: `print(pdf_urls)`

```
['https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/3t945q76s/sb397x16q/b8516938c/latest.pdf', 'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/3t945q76s/g158c396h/8910kd95z/latest.pdf', 'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/3t945q76s/w6634p60m/2v23wd923/latest.pdf', 'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/3t945q76s/q237jb60d/8910kc45j/latest.pdf', 'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/3t945q76s/02871d57q/tx31r242v/latest.pdf', 'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/3t945q76s/pz50hc74s/pz50hc752/latest.pdf', 'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/3t945q76s/79408c82d/jw827v53v/latest.pdf', 'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/3t945q76s/1544c4419/6108vs89v/latest.pdf', 'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/3t945q76s/k930cb595/8910k788h/latest.pdf', 'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/3t945q76s/st74d522v/qb98mv97t/latest.pdf', 'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/3t945q76s/sb397x16q/b8516938c/latest.pdf']
```

Answer (score 1):

A little change in your code will maybe make it:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint

base_url = 'https://usda.library.cornell.edu'

url = 'https://usda.library.cornell.edu/concern/publications/3t945q76s?locale=en#release-items'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')
b = []

page = 1
while True:
    pdf_urls = [a["href"] for a in soup.select('#release-items a[href$=".pdf"]')]
    pprint(pdf_urls)
    b.append(pdf_urls)

    m = soup.select_one('a[rel="next"][href]')
    if m and m['href'] != '#':
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(base_url + m['href']).text, 'html.parser')
    else:
        break
```

This:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).pdf, 'html.parser')
```

to:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')
```

and this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(base_url + m['href']).pdf, 'html.parser')
```

to this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(base_url + m['href']).text, 'html.parser')
```

Output:

```
['https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/3t945q76s/sb397x16q/b8516938c/latest.pdf',
 'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/3t945q76s/g158c396h/8910kd95z/latest.pdf',
 'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/3t945q76s/w6634p60m/2v23wd923/latest.pdf',
 'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/3t945q76s/q237jb60d/8910kc45j/latest.pdf',
 'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/3t945q76s/02871d57q/tx31r242v/latest.pdf',
 'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/3t945q76s/pz50hc74s/pz50hc752/latest.pdf',
 'https://downloads.usda.library.cornell.edu/usda-esmis/files/3t945q76s/79408c82d/jw827v53v/latest.pdf',...
```

And so on...